# I need help on boolean arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck on an array problem and could use some help.

> The first visitor will occupy the middle position:

```
        _ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _
```

> The next visitor will be in the middle of the empty area on the left side, as that is the longest sequence of unoccupied places:

```
        _ _ X _ _ X _ _ _ _

etc...
```

I have made a good start and need help continuing. Here's my code and please help me. I have the boolean array already created but I cant figure out how to print out the contents of it or to look and see it so I know which elements are true or false so I can fill out the rest of the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Homework06 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int answer = 0;
        String start="";

        answer=promptForNumberOfStalls();
        int[] stalls=new int[answer];
            boolean firstPerson[]=new boolean[answer];
        start=firstPerson(answer);
        occupyOneMore(answer, start, firstPerson);
    }

    public static int promptForNumberOfStalls (){
        int answer =0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello, how many stalls will there be");
        answer = keyboard.nextInt();
        return answer;
    }
    public static String firstPerson( int answer){
        boolean[] firstPerson = new boolean[answer];
        String start="";
        for(int i=0;i<firstPerson.length;i++){
            if(firstPerson[i])
                start+="X";
            else
                start+="_";
        }
        return start;
    }

    public static boolean[] occupyOneMore(int answer, String start, boolean[] firstPerson){
    int middle=answer/2+1;
    firstPerson[answer/2+1]=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstPerson.length; i++) {
        if (firstPerson[i] == true) {
            middle = (int) Math.floor(i / 2); // use Math.ceil to round up
            System.out.println(middle);

            if(middle==i){
                  firstPerson[i]=true;
              }
        }

    }



    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstPerson));
    return firstPerson;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You haven't asked a specific question. My strong advice is to create an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org). Include specifics like sample I put and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
int answer = 0;
boolean firstPerson[] = new boolean[answer];
```

The first problem is your array starts off with a length of 0. Arrays are fixed so you gotta define the size.

PS: us doing your homework for you won't help.

**Edit:** with regards to your comment

You have to find middle of the left side. So loop through the array and find the size until you hit a true value.

```
int middleLeft;
for (int i = 0; i < firstPerson.length; i++) {
    if (firtPerson[i] == true) {
        middleLeft = (int) Math.floor(i / 2); // use Math.ceil to round up
    }
}
```

once you have the `middleLeft` variable put a `true` value at that location in the array.

Comment: Thank you very much. I always forget to move my array after I get the answer from a method. Do you have any tips on where to go in the last method?

Comment: I'm not asking for answers, just a hint on what I need to focus on next. I have been staring at this for hours and just want an incentive to keep going.

Comment: So far I have created a boolean array so I can know which positions have already been filled and I have got the answer from the user. Right now Im trying to fill the boolean array with the positions of the filled stalls and im stuck.

Answer (score 0):

To print the contents of an array, use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
boolean[] ba = new boolean[]{true,true,false,true};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ba));
```

will produce the output

```
[true,true,false,true]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use something like this for printing values inside your loop:

```
System.out.println(firstPerson[s] ? "true" : "false");
```

or use `System.out.print(...);` to keep values on the same line.

Comment: ok. I have put all of your code to use and now im tryin to make "middle" register as true. Edited.